# NSIS WriteINIStr is not what I expect

Tags: nsis

This code does some odd things:

```
InstallDir "$PROGRAMDATA\Ctream\CSOI\logs"   

WriteINIStr "$TEMP\Config.ini" "SQL" "DbName" $SOMEGLOBAL
WriteINIStr "$INSTDIR\Config.ini" "SQL" "Usr" $SOMEGLOBAL
```

- In the tempfile folder, the ini has 
  [SQL]
  DbName=$SOMEGOBAL (its defined elsewhere)
- the $instdir folder has no ini file.

I must be missing basic NSIS stuff here, any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `RequestExecutionLevel Admin` to your script. Only elevated administrators are allowed to write to `$ProgramFiles`.